# Why do removeContent(), removeChild(), and detach() not work?

Tags: java, xml, removechild

I have an XML file with a list where each element only has an attribute, and I'm trying to delete a specific element, but it doesn't work. My Java code for deleting is:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document readDoc;

        try {
            readDoc = builder.build(new File(INACTIVE_FILE));

            List<Element> inactiveDocList = readDoc.getRootElement().getChild("inactiveDoctorList").getChildren();

            for(Element e: inactiveDocList){
                if(e.getAttributeValue("inactiveDoctorID").equals("1")){
                    e.removeContent();      
                }
            }
            XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
            xmlOutput.output(readDoc.getRootElement(), new FileOutputStream(new File(INACTIVE_FILE)));      
        } 
        catch (JDOMException | IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And my XML is:

```
<root>
  <inactiveDoctorList>
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="1" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="2" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="4" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="16" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="3" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="9" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="13" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="14" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="11" />
    <doctor inactiveDoctorID="6" />
  </inactiveDoctorList>
</root>
```

When I do e.removeContent() or e.removeChild("doctor") nothing happens, and when I try e.detach() I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: The ContentList supporting the FilterList this iterator is processing has been modified by something other than this Iterator.
    at org.jdom2.ContentList$FilterListIterator.checkConcurrent(ContentList.java:1309)
    at org.jdom2.ContentList$FilterListIterator.next(ContentList.java:1357)
    at org.jdom2.ContentList$FilterListIterator.next(ContentList.java:1260)
    at edu.miami.cis324.swing.jfarache.RestorePatDoc.reactivate(RestorePatDoc.java:61)
    at edu.miami.cis324.swing.jfarache.MainFrame$13.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:741)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am a little weak at XML processing, but... which content or child would be removed from `<doctor inactiveDoctorID="1" />`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the underlying collection from inside a for-each loop, you'll need a while loop or an actual iterator instead.

It doesn't work with a for-each loop because removing (or adding) elements means the loop won't know what element to show next anymore. I don't know about removeContent() or removeChild() but that's why detach() was throwing that exception.

Comment: Miraculously, that fixed it! Could you explain why this is the case? That is to say, why does an enhanced for loop not work here? Thank you Harry!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `e` is scoped within the for-each loop. Modifying it will not modify `readDoc`

EDIT: scratch that, I guess I'm wrong. Can't win em all.

Comment: Wrong... read Blargle's answer. Your explanation does not explain the exception thrown.

Comment: Wait...waitwaitwait...so you're telling me that if he were to use a standard for loop, instead of the for-each loop, and he did exactly what he's doing above, it _would_ change `readDoc`? If that's seriously the case...well...then I learned something today. Full disclosure, I don't usually get stuck using SAX, I end up with DOM+XPAth more often than not...

Comment: More than I have used it recently, it is a matter of logic... the only way the exception may be thrown when `e.detach` is invoked if if `inactiveDocList` is a reference to the original children list (instead of a copy) AND `e.detach` removes the node from such a list.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Ok, I guess I was wrong. Thanks for the info!